Temperature dependence of heat capacity
Sometimes I find a graph of Cp/T vs T, where Cp is a heat capacity of a material and T is the temperature. What is the physical meaning of this graph? Which property can you know from the plot?

if $C_p$ denotes the stored heat (thermal energy) capacity then $\frac{C_p}{T}$ is the stored entropy capacity.
